How do we handle site members who have a pattern of leaving unfriendly initial comments?
I've noticed that, on occasion, some members of our community leave comments which could be taken as unfriendly, particularly to new posters.
The comments sometimes make uncharitable assumptions, sometimes correct the poster's grammar in a terse way (we have an edit mechanism for this), and in general leave a bad impression of our community.
I don't want to respond to such comments, as this generally derails the discussion itself. What tools do we have for this on the site?

Needless to say, flagging certainly is a way to get comments removed (and has worked on a case-by-case basis), but I don't see the pattern of behaviour changing. Is there any tool in the admin's toolbox such as a timeout, or is this not really how things work on SE?

Yes please flag such comments. The mods can issue warnings and suspensions to users who are writing unfriendly or unconstructive comments.

Do moderators have tools to realize that a pattern is emerging, when they see an individual comment flagged? I've also noticed patterns like this before, and I didn't know how to let moderators know about it, as I assume writing a post here about an individual user would be rude, counterproductive, and inappropriate. But sometimes individual users are a problem and when I am a mod myself (on places other than SE), I sometimes end up dealing with individual reports not realizing that there is a pattern unless it's pointed out to me... probably my own limitation, but I guess tools would help.
